# Node.js Socket.io adapter creating multiple "join-room" connections on page refresh

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Every time a client refreshes the page an additional instance of the socket adapter's "join-room" event listener is fired.  First it shows the client disconnect event, then the multiple "join-room" events and finally the connection event.

Eventually I get this warning: `(node:863) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 join-room listeners added to [Adapter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit (Use 'node --trace-warnings ...' to show where the warning was created)`

Logs:

```
socket.io: User connected:  F3N09wOefsqpNc32AAAB
socket a-wXTgd4OUrCWv7DAAAD has joined room a-wXTgd4OUrCWv7DAAAD
socket.io: User connected:  a-wXTgd4OUrCWv7DAAAD
socket.io: User disconnected:  F3N09wOefsqpNc32AAAB
socket DEkkVVUnGoP9c4kzAAAH has joined room DEkkVVUnGoP9c4kzAAAH
socket DEkkVVUnGoP9c4kzAAAH has joined room DEkkVVUnGoP9c4kzAAAH
socket.io: User connected:  DEkkVVUnGoP9c4kzAAAH
socket.io: User disconnected:  DEkkVVUnGoP9c4kzAAAH
socket 6jYs2BF3iM-PR67RAAAJ has joined room 6jYs2BF3iM-PR67RAAAJ
socket 6jYs2BF3iM-PR67RAAAJ has joined room 6jYs2BF3iM-PR67RAAAJ
socket 6jYs2BF3iM-PR67RAAAJ has joined room 6jYs2BF3iM-PR67RAAAJ
socket.io: User connected:  6jYs2BF3iM-PR67RAAAJ
...

socket.io: User connected:  Ed2xrTrQsJuXQJdAAAAT
socket.io: User disconnected:  Ed2xrTrQsJuXQJdAAAAT
socket WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV has joined room WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV
socket WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV has joined room WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV
socket WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV has joined room WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV
socket WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV has joined room WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV
socket WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV has joined room WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV
socket WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV has joined room WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV
socket WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV has joined room WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV
socket WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV has joined room WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV
socket WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV has joined room WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV
socket.io: User connected:  WXglcjwFryvQMgMNAAAV
(node:863) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 join-room listeners added to [Adapter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Code:

```js
const express = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { instrument } = require("@socket.io/admin-ui");
const { generateRoomId } = require('./utils');

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["https://example.com", "https://admin.socket.io"],
    credentials: true
  }
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log("socket.io: User connected: ", socket.id);

  socket.on('newGame', () => {
    let roomId = generateRoomId(8);

    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.emit('joined', roomId);
  });

  socket.on('joinGame', (roomId) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.emit('joined', roomId);
  });

  io.of("/").adapter.on("join-room", (room, id) => {
    console.log(`socket ${id} has joined room ${room}`);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("socket.io: User disconnected: ", socket.id);
  });
});

instrument(io, {
  auth: false
});

httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 3030);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting duplicate event handlers installed because this:

```
io.of("/").adapter.on("join-room", onJoinRoom);
```

is inside of this:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {   /* it's in here */  });
```

So, everytime you get a new connection, you add yet another listener with this:

```
io.of("/").adapter.on("join-room", onJoinRoom);
```

Thus, you end up with more and more duplicate event handlers for the `join-room` event as they just accumulate over time.  Eventually, you hit the warning about a possible leak from the eventlistener class because it detects a bunch of duplicate listeners.

I would suggest that you just move this:

```
io.of("/").adapter.on("join-room", onJoinRoom);
```

outside of the `io.on('connection', ...);` block so that it's at the top level and only ever executed once like this:

```
const express = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { instrument } = require("@socket.io/admin-ui");
const { generateRoomId } = require('./utils');

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["https://example.com", "https://admin.socket.io"],
    credentials: true
  }
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log("socket.io: User connected: ", socket.id);

  socket.on('newGame', () => {
    let roomId = generateRoomId(8);

    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.emit('joined', roomId);
  });

  socket.on('joinGame', (roomId) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    socket.emit('joined', roomId);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("socket.io: User disconnected: ", socket.id);
  });
});

// log join room events    
io.of("/").adapter.on("join-room", (room, id) => {
  console.log(`socket ${id} has joined room ${room}`);
});

instrument(io, {
  auth: false
});

httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 3030);
```

The only event handlers you should be adding inside `io.on('connection', ...)` are socket-specific event handlers that are on that specific socket.  If you add global event handlers in there that you don't explicitly remove, then you will be creating duplicate event handlers.